# Working with HTML tag completion in Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

What are good secrets for improving and using HTML tag completion in Sublime?

Personally, I'm looking for a way to keep the default functionality (if I type `<a ...>Link text</`, the closing `a` tag is completed) but at times I want to disable, maybe temporarily disable, that functionality (if I'm making a list and purposefully leaving off the closing `li` tags). (I'm not liking that if I type `<ul> <li>Something <li>Something else </`, Sublime closes my `li` tag when I want it to close my `ul` tag.)

If I frequently find myself in the above situation with various tags, is there a better solution than disabling auto complete functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to deal with the problem, though it's more a bandaid solution.

Just close your `<li>` tags like this `<li/>`. This has no effect on the rendered output, but Sublime Text will no longer automatically close it.